# Bubble sort is not sorting array properly in c

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement, average, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a program for my C class that tracks deposits made at a bank. It gives you a menu with the options to input a deposit, show the sum of all the deposits, show the deposits from highest to lowest (using a bubble sort), show the average deposit, show the lowest deposit, and then a quit option. The input, the sum, and the quit options are working just fine, as far as I can tell, but the other three options are broken. When you choose them, no matter what inputs you have made to the array, it acts like they're all equal to zero. This is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main()

{
    int sortCount, sortCount2, sortCount3, swap;// variables for sort
    int depositCount = 0, sumCount, lowestCount;
    int averageCount, avgSum = 0, avg; //variables for average
    char switchInput = 0;//menu input
    double deposits[100] = { 0 }, sum = 0, average;

    do 
    {
        printf("BANKING MAIN MENU\n\n");
        printf("[M]ake a new deposit\n");
        printf("[S]um of all deposits\n");
        printf("[D]eposits will be displayed from highest to lowest\n");
        printf("[A]verage of all deposits\n");
        printf("[L]owest deposit will be displayed\n");
        printf("[Q]uit\n\n");
        printf("Please enter selection:\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &switchInput);

        switch (switchInput)
        {
        case 'm': case 'M'://Deposit screen

            printf("\nPlease enter deposit:\n\n");
                scanf("%lf", &deposits[depositCount++]);//deposit input
                ;

            for (sortCount = 0; sortCount < depositCount; sortCount++)//Should sort the array highest to lowest
                for (sortCount2 = 0; sortCount2 < depositCount - sortCount - 1; sortCount2++)
                    if (deposits[sortCount] < deposits[sortCount+1])
                    {
                        swap = deposits[sortCount];
                        deposits[sortCount] = deposits[sortCount+1];
                        deposits[sortCount+1] = swap;
                    }

                break;

        case 's': case 'S'://Total of deposits screen

            for (sumCount = 0; sumCount < depositCount; sumCount++)//depositCount should have it only use parts of the array where there are inputs.
                sum = sum + deposits[sumCount];
                printf("\nYour total deposits equal $%.2lf\n\n", sum);

                break;

        case 'd': case 'D'://Highest to lowest screen


            for (sortCount3 = 0; sortCount3 < depositCount; sortCount3++)//depositCount should have it only use parts of the array where there are inputs.
            {
                printf("$%d \n", deposits[sortCount3]);
            }
            break;

        case 'a': case 'A'://Average screen

            for (sumCount = 0; sumCount < depositCount; sumCount++) //depositCount should have it only use parts of the array where there are inputs.
        {
                avgSum = avgSum + deposits[sumCount];
                avg = avgSum / depositCount;
            }
            printf("Your average deposit is $%.2lf.\n", avg);
            break;

        case 'l': case 'L'://Lowest screen

            printf("The lowest deposit is $%.2lf.\n", deposits[depositCount]);//If the numbers are ordered from highest to lowest, the then entry in the array at the position equal to the number of deposits should be the lowest

            break;

        case 'q': case 'Q'://quit screen

            printf("\nThank you for using our bank!\n\n");
            system("pause");

            return 0;
            break;

        default ://invalid option

            printf("\nInvalid selection!\n\n");
        }

    } while (switchInput != 'q'||'Q');

}
```

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wcnversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `} while (switchInput != 'q'||'Q');`  In C, can only check one thing at a time.  So this would be better written as: `} while (switchInput != 'q'|| switchInput == 'Q');`  an even better way would be to use `tolower()` from the header file; `ctype.h`  then write: `} while ( tolower( switchInput ) != 'q' );`);

Comment: Bubble sort doesn't work with `for`-loops. Please google "Bubble sort".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what you mean ? bubble sort is basically a _for_ nested in an other

Comment: @user3629249 must be `} while (switchInput != 'q' && switchInput != 'Q');`  ^^

Comment: @Bruno, bubble doesn't use for loops. It uses while loops which can use some efficiency aspects instead of just dumb iteratiing over already sorted parts.

Comment: @Bruno, more precise, it uses an outer `while (k>0)` loop with `k` the position of last interchange (all higher elements are sorted) and an inner `for (i=0; i<k; i++)` loop up to this `k`. See also Wikipedia.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie ah ok, I misunderstanding, for me "Bubble sort doesn't work with for-loops." means give a wrong result using for-loops ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bubble sort is not sorting array properly in c

in

> ```
>       for (sortCount = 0; sortCount < depositCount; sortCount++)//Should sort the array highest to lowest
>            for (sortCount2 = 0; sortCount2 < depositCount - sortCount - 1; sortCount2++)
>                if (deposits[sortCount] < deposits[sortCount+1])
>                {
>                    swap = deposits[sortCount];
>                    deposits[sortCount] = deposits[sortCount+1];
>                    deposits[sortCount+1] = swap;
>                }
> ```

`sortCount2` is unused inside the inner *for* where you do always the same thing independently of it. Furthermore you go 1 index after the last

There are plenty implementations of bubble sort on S.O. I let you search and correct

*swap* must be a *double*

---

in

> ```
> case 'a': case 'A'://Average screen
>        for (sumCount = 0; sumCount < depositCount; sumCount++) //depositCount should have it only use parts of the array where there are inputs.
>    {
>            avgSum = avgSum + deposits[sumCount];
>            avg = avgSum / depositCount;
>        }
> ```

the division must be done *after* the sums, no each time, so

```
   case 'a': case 'A'://Average screen
        for (sumCount = 0; sumCount < depositCount; sumCount++) //depositCount should have it only use parts of the array where there are inputs.
        {
            avgSum = avgSum + deposits[sumCount];
        }
         avg = avgSum / depositCount;
```

and *avgSum* and *avg* must be *double*

---

> ```
> while (switchInput != 'q'||'Q');
> ```

must be

```
while ((switchInput != 'q') && (switchInput != 'Q'));
```